# How do you change the label text in java using eclipse and scene builder?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to make a "Hello World" using eclipse and scene builder.

```
package lj.HelloWorld;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("AddressApp");

    initRootLayout();
}

/**
 * Initializes the root layout.
 */
public void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(HelloWorld.class.getResource("rootHelloWorld.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
// my attempt to refer to my label object in scenebuilder.
@FXML
private Label lblOutput;

@FXML
private void handleClick(ActionEvent event) {
    lblOutput.setText("This");
}
}
```

And this is my fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="btnClick" layoutX="98.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Click Me" />
            <Label fx:id="lblOutput" layoutX="167.0" layoutY="18.0" text="1231231" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

I just want to know how to refer the the label and change its text to "Hello World".
PS: I'm from vb.net learning java. I've tried looking for a Hello World sample on google but some sites are down and others are just too complicated for me. Like the ch.makery tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Controller class

```
package lj.HelloWorld;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
 public class FXMLDocumentController {

@FXML private Label lblOutput;

@FXML protected void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent e){
lblOutput.setText("Hello World");
}
}
```

and tell your XML the controller class

```
 <BorderPane  fx:controller="lj.HelloWorld.FXMLDocumentController"
  <Button fx:id="btnClick" layoutX="98.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false"    text="Click Me"
onAction="#handleButtonAction"/>
```

for detailed information and tutorial pls read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm

Comment: You've been faster :). @YinYangKim, you can just create Controller Classes and link them with the Scene builder to the Scene. There you can go to the Code Pane of the Button and Label, you can link the IDs to the Component and you can link handlers like the handleButtonAction to your Button. You don't actually need the ActionEvent. You can just create any Method to be executed by the Clicks.

Comment: I'm getting a `javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Kim/Documents/Workspace/Learning%20Java/bin/lj/HelloWorld/rootHelloWorld.fxml:8` error. If I'm reading this right the error is pointing to `<BorderPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="lj.HelloWorld.FXMLDocumentController">` I also found this at the bottom part of the error log `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lj.HelloWorld.FXMLDocumentController`

Comment: He can not find the controller class. Did you create a new class in the same Project with the name FXMLDocumentController in the package lj.HelloWorld?

Comment: Damn, missed the "create a new class part" sorry. I just tried overwriting my HelloWorld class. It works now. Thanks, for this and the tutorial. One question though, what is this `import javafx.scene.text.Text;`? It is underlined as "not used" in my project.

Comment: javafx.scene.text.Text is only needed for textfields if you dont use textfields u can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try referring from the instance of the label for example:
`lbl.setText("Hello World");`

Comment: He is not using Swing, he is using JavaFX. There is no such thing as JLabel

Comment: i think its fine nw !!

Comment: Not really. As you can see in the code he already did lbl.setText... But the Problem is how to link the click to the handler. So the Solution is the Controller Class and not the setText call